# Memory leaking with using same pointer to numerous target

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

My IDE is Visual Studio 2010 with integrated Intel Fortran compiler. The version of compiler is: Intel Parallel Studio XE 2011.

I am not experienced programer in Fortran so I need a little help about using pointers in reading data from `.txt` files. This is my example code:

```
Module Derived_type

implicit none

Type , public :: Something

  private

       Real :: Somth_1
    Integer :: Somth_2

  contains

    procedure , public :: read_input => read_data_input
    procedure , public :: t_Somth_1 => t_data_Somth_1
    procedure , public :: t_Somth_2 => t_data_Somth_2

End Type Something

private :: read_data_input
private :: t_data_Somth_1 , t_data_Somth_2

contains

Subroutine read_data_input( This , Un_r )

  Class( Something ) :: This
  Integer , intent( in ) :: Un_r

  Read ( Un_r , * , Err = 100 ) This%Somth_1
  Read ( Un_r , * , Err = 101 ) This%Somth_2

Return

100 Stop ( "Read format error - 100 !!!" )
101 Stop ( "Read format error - 101 !!!" )

End Subroutine read_data_input

Function t_data_Somth_1 ( This ) result( data_Somth_1 )

  Class( Something ) :: This
  Real :: data_Somth_1

  data_Somth_1 = This%Somth_1

End Function t_data_Somth_1

Function t_data_Somth_2 ( This ) result( data_Somth_2 )

  Class( Something ) :: This
  Integer :: data_Somth_2

  data_Somth_2 = This%Somth_2

End Function t_data_Somth_2

End Module Derived_type

Program Memory_leaking

Use , non_intrinsic :: Derived_type

Implicit none

Integer :: i , alloc_err , dealloc_err
Integer , parameter :: N_snv = 3
Character( 256 ) :: Name
Character(*),parameter :: a00 = '("Input_",i1,".txt")'

Class( Something ) , pointer :: Po_Something

Type( Something ) , allocatable , target :: Tar_Something(:)

! Memory allocation

allocate ( Po_Something , Stat = alloc_err )

If ( alloc_err .ne. 0 ) Stop ( "Allocation wrong - Po_Something !!!")

If ( .not. allocated ( Tar_Something ) ) allocate( Tar_Something( N_snv ) , stat = alloc_err )

If ( alloc_err .ne. 0 ) Stop ( "Allocation wrong - Tar_Something !!!")


Do i = 1 , N_snv

   Po_Something => Tar_Something(i)

   Write( Name , a00 ) i

   Open( 15 , File = Name , Status = 'Unknown' , Action = 'Read' )

      Call Po_Something%read_input( 15 )

   Close( 15 , Status = 'Keep' )

   Write(*,*) Po_Something%t_Somth_1() , Po_Something%t_Somth_2()

End Do

! Memory deallocation

deallocate ( Po_Something , Stat = dealloc_err )

If ( dealloc_err .ne. 0 ) Stop ( "deAllocation wrong - Po_Something !!!")

If ( allocated ( Tar_Something ) ) deallocate( Tar_Something, stat = dealloc_err )

If ( dealloc_err .ne. 0 ) Stop ( "deAllocation wrong - Tar_Something !!!")

End program Memory_leaking
```

I have a one array which is derived type and I want to read data from `.txt` file for every single array using same pointer, just like in my example code.
I there need for breaking conection beatwean pointer and target in afther do loop execution was done?
Is there memory leaking in this case?

Comment: I need explantion for yes if yes is the answer be
cause i want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a memory leak.

```
allocate ( Po_Something , Stat = alloc_err )
```

Here you allocated, manually, storage for your pointer variable and pointed to its memory address.

```
Po_Something => Tar_Something(i)
```

Just after, you changed the poitee to another storage (the allocatable variable) and left behind the storage you allocated before. After this pointer association, there is no reference left anymore  pointing to the address you allocated manually. The program won't be able to deallocate it when it reaches the end.

As you are not using the storage of the first allocation, the solution here is just not doing it. The pointer will point to memory already allocated in the loop.

Allocatable variables are deallocated automatically (in modern Fortran), but any memory you allocated manually for a pointer variable need to be manually deallocated before you change the its target.

Check my other answer about when manual deallocation is needed for reference.
[When is array deallocating necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634582/when-is-array-deallocating-necessary/50634764#50634764)

(better than that, download a copy of the Fortran Standard for reference here https://wg5-fortran.org )

Comment: What if the ` Po_Something` was not allocatable variable? Is there memory leak in that case? Is it necessary to nullify pointer at the end of loop?

Comment: Well,  Po_Something is not 'allocatable'. I is a 'pointer', and those are different attributes. (Both can be dynamically allocated, but that's all they have in common). Pointer variables can point to different addresses an act like the target. Allocatable variables cannot, but their memory are watched  and kind of managed automatically by the system (please check the link)

Comment: And no, it's not necessary to nullify it at the end. 'Nullify' means make it point to nowhere, it doesn't involve memory management.

Comment: So just to conlude. In case that memory was not allocated for a `Po_something` pointer variable there is no chance for a memory leak danger inside the loop?

Comment: No. If its a static variable or an allocatable variable, no memory leaks will happen. Also, if any answer solved your question you can mark it as the accepted answer. :)